# Informatica update partial data using UPDATE strategy

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to update partial data (primary key + just one or more columns) in a matching target row while leaving others intact in target as shown below or do I have to do a lookup and port all the columns?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply only connect the required ports. Note, that you need to define in your target the ID column as primary key.